# How to show list View in Google Calendar for day's events?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm new in google calendar integration and apologize if this is asked earlier:

I have created four resources for Google Calendar from my Gsuite account, as I want the column layout in frontend using the

[`<iframe src=''></iframe>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vA0K.png)

generated from integrate calendar but on frontend only the month week and agenda is showing. I have tried different solution but all of them displaying the week & month if I combined all the calendar to one, than also the view is the same

I want to integrate this only with google Iframe, although using full calendar it is also possible.

Please, kindly check the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vA0K.png): I want this backend layout, and to the frontend with an additional option of the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did understand it correctly what you want here is to have exactly [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vA0K.png) as an iframe embedded on your website.

I'm afraid this is not possible to get that view using the iframe you can obtain following this steps:

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en

If you want another view you'll have to build it yourself retrieving the data using [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference) and building the view yourself, or you can also use other existing libraries, like:

https://fullcalendar.io/

It may have a nicer view and the functionalities you are missing, take a look at it!

Comment: Is there any other alternative way to integrate that layout in frontend